# Apache Usergrid 2.x: can you restrict API access by a Data Entity's property value?

Tags: usergrid

Say I have the following API, where `users` can have zero or more `registeredIds`, which model identifiers by type (with effective dates).

[image: user-registeredid-association]

Two examples of `registeredId`s include:

```
// Social Security Number
{
    "id"       : "111-11-1111",
    "type"     : "SSN",
    "validFrom": 315554400000,
    "validTo"  : null,
    "registrationAuthority": "United States Social Security Administration"
},
// Employee ID
{
    "id"       : "12345678",
    "type"     : "employee-id",
    "validFrom": 1262325600000,
    "validTo"  : null,
    "registrationAuthority": "YoYoDyne"
}
```

When Anonymous User requests an employee, e.g.,

`https://api.usergrid.com/your-org/your-app/users/janedoe`

Anonymous User should only get a single `registeredId.type` with the `type` value "employee-id." Administrators, however, should see both the "employee-id" and "SSN" `registeredId.types`.

How would Apache Usergrid apply access control by the `registeredId.type`? I know I can [assign permissions](http://usergrid.apache.org/docs/security-and-auth/using-permissions.html), but this is too restrictive. Can I create some kind of Entity SubType? Or should I handle this through relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Usergrid does not allow you to set property validation checks. One solution to this problem is to have separate "EmployeeID" entities, have a connection from each User to that their id entity and setup permissions so that only authenticated users can access the EmployeeID entities.

Comment: Thanks, @snoopdave, that's what I suspected. I'll try it.